# React cannot read state object from axios after getting the response with then method

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a react component that calls the backend when the page loads then update the internal page state based on the Json response I use axios for that so constructor is like :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={elements:[]};
}
```

then on componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount(){
  axios.post('https://example.com/getElements').then(function(response){
    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
     this.state={[this.state.elements]: [...this.state.elements, response.data[i]['element'] ]};
}
}
```

so basically it fetches the response data which is a json object that has parents marked with numbers: 0 ,1 ,2 , etc.. until 10
Each of them has key and value so I have to presist each element from the json response to the react state object using a for loop the problem is  that trying to modify state object from axios async 'then' method makes the state object unreadable (Cannot read properties of undefined reading state).

any solution for how to fix that ?

Comment: Do not modify state directly outside of the constructor...use `setState`. Also, you should not use an array has the key for an object.

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work 
in the constructor : this.setState([]);
in update component : for(let i=0;i<9;i++){
     this.setState(
      (state) => { 
      return [response.data[i]['element']]
      }
      );
}

Comment: it only stores one object but I need to keep previous object on each iteration

Comment: I was only correcting how you update the state **outside** the constructor. When you change/set the state inside the constructor, what you had before should work just fine. When you are modifying state in other lifecycle methods, use `setState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an axios call and store the result, your code should look something like this:

```js
axios.post(url).then(response => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
     return { /* combine response with prevState as needed */ }
  })
});
```

Comment: is it possible to use setstate(); in a class component?

Comment: Yes. It is the only way to update the state in a class component.